# Parsing html elements using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have:

```
<tr>
   <td class="prodSpecAtribute">word</td>
   <td colspan="5">
      <a href="http://www.cmegroup.com/clearing/trading-practices/CMEblock-trade.html" target="_blank">another_word</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

I want to extract text in 2 td classes (word and another_word:
So I used BeautifulSoup:

This is the code Matijn Pieters was asking for:
Basically, it grabs info from html page (from a table) and stores these values in a left and right column list. Then, I create a dictionary from this details (using the left col list as the key, and for the values, I use the right col list)

```
def get_data(page):

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

left = []
right = []

#Obtain data from table and store into left and right columns
#Iterate through each row
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):

    #Find all table data(cols) in that row
    tds = tr.findAll('td')

    #Make sure there are 2 elements, a col and a row
    if len(tds) >= 2:

        #Find each entry in a row -> convert to text
        right_col = []
        inp = []
        once = 0
        no_class = 0
        for td in tds:
            if once == 0:               
                #Check if of class 'prodSpecAtribute'
                if check(td) == True:
                    left_col = td.findAll(text=True)
                    left_col_x = re.sub('&\w+;', '', str(left_col[0]))
                    once = 1
                else:
                    no_class = 1
                    break

            else:        
                right_col = td.findAll(text=True)
                right_col_x = ' '.join(text for text in right_col if text.strip())
                right_col_x = re.sub('&\w+;', '', right_col_x)
                inp.append(right_col_x)


        if no_class == 0:
            inps = '. '.join(inp)
            left.append(left_col_x)
            right.append(inps)

#Create a Dictionary for left and right cols
item = dict(zip(left, right))
return item
```

Comment: What information from the link is being copied?

Comment: Your example produces `[u'word']` and `[u'\n', u'another_word', u'\n']`, the latter including the whitespace *around* the `a` tag. Is that what you see?

Comment: Just the text in between the `<td>` tags

Comment: Note that your loop each time **replaces** `col`; nothing is being appended to the original list. Use `col.extend(td.findAll(text=True))` for that.

Comment: You are asking it for all text elements inside the `<td>` tag; did you want to filter out the whitespace-only text?

Comment: I didn't know that `col` could get replaced. Also with the current example, what I see is this: `[u'another_word', u' <strong>(Years 1-5):</strong><br  />\n   [...]']`

Comment: No, not with this current sample you won't. There evidently more `<tr><td>` sections elsewhere on your page.

Comment: _this_ is what I'm doing (now I understand what you meant by col being replaced)

Comment: Don't loop over `range(len(col))`, then access `col[i]`. Just loop over `col` *directly*: `for text in col:`.. `re.sub(.., .., text)`.

Comment: And don't use `.insert(i, x)` when all you want to do is *append* instead.

Comment: You are using `.insert()` on a *already existing list*, and I bet you a 100 internet dollars that that list was longer, and the extra text you see *was there already* and your inserts left those in place.

Comment: Please show me your **full** code, this is not BeautifulSoup's fault but a problem with how you are handling lists and inserting when appending would do.

Comment: Thanks for that, how would you get rid of the `'\n'` char in `[u'\n', u'another_word', u'\n']` this is my method: `if len(column) > 0:
        val = ' '.join(filter(lambda a: a.isalpha(), right))`

Comment: I just updated with my full code. thank you for telling me that `.insert()` is a bad way to append to a list

Comment: Use `' '.join(text for text in right if text.strip())`.

Comment: I updated the post with my full code if you were interested in seeing what was wrong. Thanks

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hey man, I don't think `.insert()` was the issue with my code, I'm using `append()` and its the same thing

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've updated the code with your recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use HTQL (http://htql.net).

Here is for your example:

```
import htql
page="""
   <tr>
      <td class="prodSpecAtribute">word</td>
      <td colspan="5">
          <a href="http://www.cmegroup.com/clearing/trading-practices/CMEblock-trade.html" target="_blank">another_word</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   """

query = """
   <tr>{ 
      c1 = <td (class='prodSpecAtribute')>1 &tx;
      c2 = <td>2 &tx &trim;
   }
   """ 

a=htql.query(page, query)
print(dict(a))
```

It prints:

```
{'word': 'another_word'}
```